# What is the outcome of getDeclaredField() method?

Tags: java

What is the functionality of getDeclaredField method in the below code ?
tempClazz is not defined anywhere in the code.Can anyone help understand the code below ?

```
private static Field getDeclaredField(Class tempClazz, String fieldName) {
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = tempClazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return field;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        tempClazz = tempClazz.getSuperclass();
        if (tempClazz == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        field = getDeclaredField(tempClazz, fieldName);
        return field;
    }
    return field;
}
```

Comment: Well `tempClazz` is a parameter - you'd pass an argument into the method. It's really unclear what you're asking...

Comment: That method should actually throw a `NoSuchFieldException` (retrow it, to be more precise). Not a lot of point in wrapping it like this method does, and this way of exception messages will get confusing, since it will basically always say "no such field on java.lang.Object", saying nothing about types you actually did query.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is:

```
private static Field getDeclaredField(Class tempClazz
```

It is a parameter to that method!

And for the meaning of that method: simply study its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)):

> Returns a Field object that reflects the specified declared field of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String that specifies the simple name of the desired field.